# Initialize button text as Date value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I have a button on UI. When the Page gets loaded, the value of the button should get set to Date value by default. Can someone tell me how to do it. I am new to this.

```
<div>
 <button id="appDate" ></button>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var now = new Date();
$('#appDate').val(now);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the button in your code is correct, but you probably want the value to be visible in the button, so you are looking also for the `text` function.

Check this snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var now = new Date();
  $('#appDate').val(now);
  $('#appDate').text(now);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <button id="appDate" ></button>
</div>
```

In order to set the format of the date to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` you need to do some work with the `Date()` object:

```js
now = new Date();
y = now.getFullYear();
m = now.getMonth()+1;
d = now.getDate();
h = now.getHours();
mi = now.getMinutes();
full_date = y + '-' + (m<10?'0'+m:m) + '-' + (d<10?'0'+d:d) + ' ' + (h<10?'0'+h:h) + ':' +(mi<10?'0'+mi:mi);
console.log(full_date);
```

Comment: Thank you and can you tell me how to get the value in this format 1986-04-08 12:30? 
that is "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

Comment: @HenryDev Thank you

Comment: @chan, the other answer is not correct. Check my answer.

Comment: @Dekel what do you mean not correct?? Your answer adds the 0 to the number if its less than 10 THAT IS ALL. My answer is not wrong at all

Comment: 1. your answer doesn't include the `hh:mm` he asked. 2. You are wrong with  the getMonth(). the getMonth() returns numbers from 0 to 11 (not from 1 to 12). 3. You are not returning the month/date format in 2 digits (but only 1).

Comment: Besides - I think the my answer should be the one the is accepted here (because i was the first to provide it). I think it's fair enough.

Comment: Just saying :) but the OP can do what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use **text method**. Here's a working solution. Hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var now = new Date();
  var a = now.getFullYear();
  var b = now.getMonth() + 1;
  var currentDay = now.getDate();
  var currentHours    = now.getHours();
  var currentMinutes  = now.getMinutes();
  
  var currentDay = (currentDay < 10) ? "0" + currentDay : currentDay;
  var currentHours = (currentHours < 10) ? "0" + currentHours : currentHours;
  var currentMinutes = (currentMinutes < 10) ? "0" + currentMinutes : currentMinutes;
  $('#appDate').text(a+"-"+b+"-"+currentDay +" "+currentHours+":"+currentMinutes);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
 <button id="appDate" ></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you notice that the exact answer already exists before posting?

Comment: @Dekel Yup saw it, but your answer is using val and text methods at the same time, it may look confusing to Chan.

Comment: yes i knew it, only thing is I didn't know the method text() to make it visible.
Can you tell me how to get the value in this format 1986-04-08 12:30? that is "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"